# Firefox Permission Denied Errors in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, firefox, zfs

The OS is Ubuntu 22.04. This OS installation is highly customized.  It has a ZFS encrypted file system, and RAID. The details, if you wish to see them, can be downloaded here:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/2w8mdb96tbzslub/Ubuntu_22.04_Root_on_ZFS_Encryption.odt/file

The problem I have now is when firefox is launched from the Konsole terminal emulator there are many permission denied errors. These are pasted below. Although firefox does run, and I am able to browse the web with it, these are not errors that can be ignored. Obviously firefox does not have needed permissions. What permissions does it need? How are they normally obtained? What should be done about them?

The errors:

```
$ firefox
2022/07/19 17:59:48.273436 cmd_run.go:1053: WARNING: cannot start document portal: Expected portal at "/run/user/1000/doc", got "/home/stephen/.cache/doc"
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/gtk-doc /usr/share/gtk-doc none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/var/lib": permission denied
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/libreoffice/help /usr/share/libreoffice/help none bind,ro 0 0): cannot create directory "/usr/share/libreoffice/help": permission denied
update.go:85: cannot change mount namespace according to change mount (/var/lib/snapd/hostfs/usr/share/xubuntu-docs /usr/share/xubuntu-docs none bind,ro 0 0): cannot open directory "/var/lib": permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/1000': Permission denied
Gtk-Message: 18:00:12.253: Failed to load module "colorreload-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 18:00:12.253: Failed to load module "window-decorations-gtk-module"
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.

(firefox:16099): dconf-CRITICAL **: 18:00:13.676: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/snap.firefox/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(firefox:16099): dconf-WARNING **: 18:00:13.676: unable to open file '/etc/dconf/db/site': Failed to open file ?/etc/dconf/db/site?: open() failed: No such file or directory; expect degraded performance

(firefox:16099): dconf-CRITICAL **: 18:00:13.676: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/snap.firefox/dconf': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
```

Comment: `firefox` in *jammy* runs as a confined *snap* package; meaning it runs with restrictions to your root file-system so access to many directories outside of $HOME or the user directory are restricted; which is intended & a security bonus of the *confined* environment.   These should not impact normal or expected usage of the program.

Comment: The computer I am preparing to migrate from has Ubuntu 21.04 (actually Pop!_OS 21.04), codename hirsute. When I launch firefox in its terminal emulator I get no errors at all. In this Ubuntu 22.04 I will migrate to, which is the one I get the errors I posted, I see words like "CRITICAL", and modules it cannot load. These messages are concerning. It is difficult for me to believe these do not mean loss of functionality. Is this snap package confinement a major difference between hirsute, and jammy? Are the same errors expected of any firefox installation in jammy?

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use the Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu & flavors are the many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of it's support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: Don't forget `firefox` differs in Ubuntu and Pop OS, let alone it differing in 21.04 (long ago [EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/)) and later releases (esp. 22.04; it was available in two ways in 21.10 in which 21.04 *release-upgraded* to).

Comment: Pop!_OS is based on Ubuntu. Really it is mostly Ubuntu. The computer I am migrating to is currently Ubuntu only, it is the computer I have trouble with, and the one for which I opened this discussion. The intent is to install Pop!_OS on top of the current Ubuntu 22.04 Studio installation in the computer I will migrate to once all problems are solved. That has not yet happened.

Answer (score 0):

These problems are solved. How they were solved I described in this thread:
http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=3097766

My installation document I linked to when I opened this thread has been updated at the link provided.

Comment: That is IMHO not a solution but a workaround. The snap installation needs to be fixed